# SWIFT calling a method to return an array and get compile error

Tags: swift

in Swift I created a class called ProductList

in this class I retrieve JSON into a ProductInfo class and then add it to an array.  But when I call the method trying to get an array returned I get a weird compile error

This is how I called it and get a compile error saying “'(String) -> Array' is not convertible to ‘[ProductInfo]’"

```
productArray = ProductList.getListOfProducts(“73")
```

I defined the function like so:

```
class ProductList {
    var category = Category()
    var productArray:[ProductInfo] = []


func getListOfProducts(item:String) ->Array<ProductInfo> {

    println("==== Items ====")
    var url=NSURL(string:"http://www.mywebsite.com/JSONGET.php?id="+item)
    var data=NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)

    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
        if let feed = json["items"] as? NSArray {
           for entry in feed {

            var product = ProductInfo()
            product.productId = entry["id"] as String

            productArray.append(product)

        }
    }
}
 return productArray
}
}
```

Comment: `getListOfProducts` you defined is an instance method, but not a class method. So, you have to call it via an instance of `ProductList`, not directly via `Product` class. Like this: `let o = ProductList(); productArray = o.getListOfProducts("73")`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return [ProductInfo]

As in

```
func getListOfProducts(item:String) -> [ProductInfo] {
...
}
```